# Push pull on couchabase server side thro' couchbase lite client side

Tags: couchbase-lite

i have tried to create one small java code to handle couchbase lite database and to do push pull operation

senario in depth is as follows

what i did is i have created bucket named as sync_gateway,
and conected with couchbase server by below config.json

```
{
"interface":":4984", 
"adminInterface":":4985",
"databases":{ 
"db":{ 
"server":"http://localhost:8091", 
"bucket":"sync_gateway",
"sync":function(doc) {
channel(doc.channels);
}
}
}
}
```

this had created metadata in sync_gateway bucket on server,
the n i have written sample java code for local database CBL , and wrote functions for push pull operations ...
code:

```
package com.Testing_couchbaseLite;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.ldap.ManageReferralControl;

import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;

import com.couchbase.lite.Context;
import com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException;
import com.couchbase.lite.Database;
import com.couchbase.lite.Document;
import com.couchbase.lite.JavaContext;
import com.couchbase.lite.Manager;
import com.couchbase.lite.ManagerOptions;
import com.couchbase.lite.QueryOptions;
import com.couchbase.lite.replicator.Replication;
import com.couchbase.lite.support.HttpClientFactory;

public class Test_syncGateWay {


    private URL createSyncURL(boolean isEncrypted){
        URL syncURL = null;
        String host = "https://localhost";  //sync gateway ip
        String port = "4984";              //sync gateway port
        String dbName = "db";
        try {
            syncURL = new URL(host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName);
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
        return syncURL;
    }

    private void startReplications() throws CouchbaseLiteException {


        try {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("id", "1");
            map.put("name","ram");

            Manager man = new Manager(new JavaContext(), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
            Database db = man.getDatabase("sync_gateway");
            Document doc = db.createDocument();
            doc.putProperties(map);

            System.out.println("-------------done------------");



            System.out.println(man.getAllDatabaseNames());
            System.out.println(man.getDatabase("sync_gateway").getDocumentCount());

        System.out.println(db.getDocument("1").getCurrentRevisionId());         

            System.out.println(db.exists());


              Replication pull = db.createPullReplication(this.createSyncURL(true));
            Replication push = db.createPushReplication(this.createSyncURL(true));
           pull.setContinuous(true);
            push.setContinuous(true);
           pull.start();
            push.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    private void createDatabase() throws CouchbaseLiteException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CouchbaseLiteException, IOException {
        new Test_syncGateWay().startReplications();



    }
}
```

now i am stating sync gateway by that config file and running java code to create document on CBL and CB server by push pull operation.

bt it is showing error as

```
Jul 08, 2016 10:27:21 AM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
SEVERE: RemoteRequest: RemoteRequest{GET, https://localhost:4984/db/_local/2eafda901c4de2fe022af262d5cc7d1c0cb5c2d2}: executeRequest() Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated. url: https://localhost:4984/db/_local/2eafda901c4de2fe022af262d5cc7d1c0cb5c2d2
```

so is there any misunderstanding in my concept??? and how do i resolve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

You have not set up your Sync Gateway for SSL.  You need to add the [SSLCert and SSLPass keys](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/wiki/SSL-support) to your config file.